# jquery mobile navbar isn't going active

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Im working on a highly dynamic app.  Due to how much stuff gets pushed around, I created a template to load all my actual content into:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>      
<?php echo $head ?>
<body>
    <?php if ($pagetype = 1) { $segment = 1 ;} else { $segment = 2; } ?>
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="<?php echo $this->uri->segment($segment)?>">

    <div data-id="pageheader" data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-position="fixed">
        <?php echo $header ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <?php echo $scripts ?>
        <?php echo $notification_list ?>
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-position-fixed="true" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">        
        <?php echo $nav ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <?php echo $footer ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the problem is in the `footer` where `$footer` loads my navbar:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>structures/info/<?php echo $str_info['str_id'] ?>" data-icon="info" >Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>structures/upgrade/<?php echo $str_info['str_id'] ?>" data-icon="gear" >Upgrade</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>structures/recruit/<?php echo $str_info['str_id'] ?>" data-icon="refresh" ">Recruit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear" >City</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear" >Military</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any easily viewable reason as to why the navbar isn't functioning at all?  The links work, but they never go active unless i specify it manually..

`<?php if ($pagetype = 1) { $segment = 1 ;} else { $segment = 2; } ?>` was just a way to play around with the page name.

Comment: Your code seems ok... What do you mean exactly by "They never go active" ? And what do you need to specify "manually" to make it work?

Comment: if i add, `class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist` for instance, it will remain active forever...no matter what page I change to.  My problem is, no matter which page I am on, the active class never stays up.

Comment: you know..i think my problem was that I thought jquery changed its active class for me automatically...Do I need to adjust it myself? o_O? im assuming thats it.

Comment: jQuery should normally take care of the active state automatically... Look at the example: "Navbars in footers" of the last JQM version doc: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navbar/ .The active state is working and the source code is very similar to yours...

Comment: Can it be a problem/conflict related the JQM css included in your page? Which jq and jqm versions are you using?

Comment: i removed my custom css and it didn't change unfortunately.  I tried copying exactly what they had in their docs...thats why im confused.  Does page id have anything to do with it?

Comment: Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/NsWQ4/5/, I created a page that contain your exact same page without PHP code... The Navbar in footer is working normally...

Comment: Ricky I think I understand your problem. You have multiple pages created from the same template. Because of data-id="footer" it looks like pages are not changing (when they indeed do) and when page is changed last activated tab is not active any more?

Comment: ^i think thats pretty much it.  I don't know the inside of javacsript and the DOM as well as I should, so im not sure what I should do in this case.